# How can I just get content inside a shortcode or just outside

Tags: shortcode

Suppose I have content like

```
[xxx]
Here is some content in xxx 
[/xxx]

Here is content outside xxx ...
```

Can I somehow just get

1. content inside `[xxx]` ONLY
2. content outside `[xxx]` ONLY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the shortcode. If you have access to the shortcode's handler function, that function's second argument is the content inside the shortcode:

```
function wpse20136_shortcode( $atts, $content ){
  // $content has the content inside xxx
}

register_shortcode( 'xxx', 'wpse20136_shortcode' );
```

For getting all content not in shortcodes, that's easy. `strip_shortcodes()` does that:

```
strip_shortcodes( get_the_content() );
```

for example, will give you the content of the current post with only the content not inside shortcodes.